# Is there a helpful ressources for designing an architecture of a blockchain in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

**I really tried different search and I'm tiered of bitcoins and cryptocurrency as result in search engines**

Comment: Here is the resource you are looking for. Explain what you are trying to do, what you have so far, and what exactly the problem is, and someone may be able to help you. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer official Hyperledger Fabric doc. https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3/deployment_guide_overview.html